# Using NSSet/allTargets to get the xib so-called "File owner"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicontrol

Looking at this image, you can see that a UIView loaded from a nib has a "File Owner"

[image]

## Notice in the xib, Apple has labelled something "File Owner".

So, open Xcode, open any xib, look at Placeholders, and look directly underneath, to see:

## "File Owner".

In this particular example, the "xib-file-owner" happens to be **the class LoginScreen.**

So, at run time, for a specific thing created by this xib, the "was-xib-file-owner" (to coin a phrase) will in fact be:

## It will be: some particular instance of the class LoginScreen.

Now at run time. Obviously, in a UIView, with every UIButton, you can simply call

```
[self.someButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];
```

and you get to indeed "go to", precisely:

## You go to: that **instance of the class LoginScreen**.

*{Note - OF COURSE, the UIButton could be pointed anywhere at all. I am asking about the case where we know for a fact the UIButton is indeed pointing to the "was-xib-file-owner" of the UIButton.}*

In fact, the method [`allTargets`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/allTargets) will indeed return that target (in this case some **instance of the class LoginScreen**) as part of the N target(s) it returns, and indeed the selector(s), etc etc.

I'm not good enough to write code for allTargets, NSSet, etc.

Can someone show me how to extract, using allTargets and some computer code, the **instance of the class LoginScreen**?  ie the running instance of the "was-xib-file-owner" seen in the xib? Cheers.

---

Later:

bizarrely, the answer to this question is, essentially and generally:

## [self.allTargets anyObject]

since, if created from the xib there will only be the one, and, it is precisely what is described in bold above. To repeat: *OF COURSE, the UIButton could be pointed ANYWHERE AT ALL. I am asking about the case where we know for a fact the UIButton is indeed pointing to the "was-xib-file-owner" of the UIButton.*

In that ("normal") case the answer is indeed just that surprisingly simple -- [self.allTargets anyObject].

Comment: why would you need the owner of the button ?

Comment: You mean owner or container?

Comment: there are N targets and 1 superview... 0 owners

Comment: For the record:  giora: it's a bizarre question, note that the apple method sendActionsForControlEvents, for example, "needs" to know that.  anoop/daij:  I mean the "was-xib-file-owner".  Of course there is no "file owner" at runtime, so I mean the "was-xib-file-owner". I have edited to spell this out in the question over and over, since it might help someone in the future!  Cheers men, awesome QA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no file owner (as seen in IB) known to views at runtime. The information about the file owner isn't there. Closest you can do is check the target's class:

```
    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(allTargets)]) {
        NSSet *owners = self.allTargets;
                    for(id owner in owners) {
                        if([owner isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
                           NSLog(@"owner: %@", owner);
                    }
            }
```

or just assume target is owner

```
    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(allTargets)]) {
        id owner = [self.allTargets anyObject];
        NSLog(@"owner: %@", owner);
    }
```

Comment: again: there is no owner as Anoop in his answer said: "
File's owner is nothing but a proxy, which takes the class at runtime."

Comment: no there is no file owner at runtime... that information isn't there.

Comment: Danke .. It's quite funny that the actual answer to the question is basically:  **[self.allTargets anyObject]** !  :)  You know, I'm curious why you check respondsToSelector ..?  (If it's a UIButton, you can call allTargets; the question is about UIButton.)  Were you just being careful, or is there something I don't know? Cheers!

Comment: just being careful: defensive programming

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no "owner" for a button.

A UIButton is a subview of a specific view, in IB, you drag your button in a certain view and then the button becomes a subview of this view. To retrieve the superview of the button, you call `[myButton superview];`

Then a Button can be referenced as a property or iVar of a certain class but it's something else.

Comment: No, I mean dragging a button from the library to the view. When you say "owner" you refer to the file's owner displayed in IB? As such it's usually a VC or it can also be a view. With NSSet you can access one random object with the method anyObject but I'm not sure that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @JoeBlow there is no owner like that

Answer (score 1):

You have a `UIButton`, and it has targets attached for certain control events (commonly `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`).

You can fetch the targets of a `UIButton` as follows

```
NSSet *targets = [myButton allTargets];

for( NSObject *target in targets )
{
    //Do something with target

    //Maybe it's a view:
    if( [target isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] )
    {
        //Do something to view specific target
    }
}
```

It is important to note two things:

Targets **are not** the "owners" of a `UIButton`, nor do they need to be UIViews (if I understand your question correctly). Targets can be *any object*, generally they will be derived from `NSObject`.

"File's Owner" in Interface Builder is just a term for the `UIViewController` (generally) which "owns" the nib — it *may or may not be* the target of the button!

If you know for certain that your button has your File's Owner as a target, then you can check for it in the following way (though I would not recommend coding like this):

```
//Assuming your File Owner is "LoginScreen" as in your picture
NSSet *targets = [myButton allTargets];

for( NSObject *target in targets )
{
    //Is the target our File Owner class type?
    if( [target isKindOfClass:[LoginScreen class]] )
    {
        LoginScreen *login = (LoginScreen *)target

        //Do something with `login` 
    }
}
```

A better way would be to recursively check the [nextResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/nextResponder) of your UIButton until you hit your managing view controller. I haven't tested the following code, but it follows the documentation:

```
UIResponder *responder = [myButton nextResponder];

while( [responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]] == NO &&
       responder != nil )
{
    responder = [responder nextResponder];
}

//If your button is "owned" in the responder chain
// by a UIViewController, then `responder` will be it
// otherwise `responder` will be nil
if( responder )
{
    //Do something
}
```

I don't know why you need to do this, however. Perhaps there is a simpler solution to your problem?

Comment: Simeon, in your code example two, line 7: ** isKindOfClass:[LoginScreen class]**  I have two puzzles there:  (A) you're assuming I the programmer knows it was LoginScreen class; isn't there a more general solution? (ie, I'm asking "for a UIButton, how to determine what the class is of the FileOwner on the xib...").  And (B) that could match "any" instance of LoginScreen (I believe?), I want to find the actual LoginScreen (very likely a UIViewController) which is indeed the FileOwner of that xib.  Any thoughts?!  :)

Comment: The more general solution might be to check `isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]`, as that would find any view controller attached to the button as a target. The latter part of my solution (using `nextResponder`) will find the nearest view controller "parent" of your button — that may or may not be attached as a target, however.

Comment: Maybe the best answer is that, if you the programmer know that the UIButton was a common-type of UIButton, where indeed **all** the targets are indeed the instance-of-the-FileOwnerClass: then, simply take the first item at line 9 of Simeon's code (it wouldn't matter which one) .. and indeed that's the answer. (The fact that the targets were indeed created via loading an xib and using the "FileOwner" {which is understood/known by the xib-loader} is completely unknown to the UIView/UIButton itself.)  There is NO flag on a control 'oh, this target happened to be loaded from the xib/FileOwner".

Comment: simeon, although you were the first to understand and indeed explain in detail the situation, it seemed appropriate to click the "bounty" to daij since he gave the conclusive code (I now use it!) and indeed he was labouring away on the issue before hand.  I hope that's OK with both you guys.  (It's silly one can't just click as many "bounties" as one wishes.)  THank you again very much, Simeon!!